# rviz2 does not show the images published on the topic

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I echoed the topic of senor_images/Image and I see the image matrix on the terminal containing values but when use rviz2 to display this image, rviz2 does not show the image and shows this info on terminal:

INFO] [1599639372.778484561] [rviz]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'head_camera1_rgb_optical_frame' at time 1599639371.222 for reason 'Unknown'

I see the topic on rviz2 but there is not image. Did anyone have this case before?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/361185/rviz2-does-not-show-the-images-published-on-the-topic/) by [macieksz](https://answers.ros.org/users/37526/macieksz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2020-09-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer is to assign the fixed frame to camera frame!

---

Originally posted by [macieksz](https://answers.ros.org/users/37526/macieksz/) with karma: 36 on 2020-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mbuijs](https://answers.ros.org/users/33718/mbuijs/) on 2020-09-21**:
Can you mark this as the correct answer?